# How to get elements from NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, nsarray

I have an NSArray built from json data from twitter REST API.

```
NSArray *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];

NSLog (@"Element %@", [dict objectAtIndex: 1]);
```

How to get individual elements from the array, one of the array index item looks like:

```
Element 1 = {
    contributors = "<null>";
    coordinates = "<null>";
    "created_at" = "Tue Feb 07 11:15:08 +0000 2012";
    entities =     {
        hashtags =         (
        );
        urls =         (
        );
        "user_mentions" =         (
        );
    };
    favorited = 0;
    geo = "<null>";
    id = 166842424398848000;
    "id_str" = 166842424398848000;
    "in_reply_to_screen_name" = "<null>";
    "in_reply_to_status_id" = "<null>";
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str" = "<null>";
    "in_reply_to_user_id" = "<null>";
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str" = "<null>";
    place = "<null>";
    "retweet_count" = 0;
    retweeted = 0;
    source = web;
    text = "another day is here so ready to be off from work already...";
    ....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try,

```
NSString *string = [[dict objectAtIndex: 1] objectForKey:@"keyName"];
```

There's a sub dictionary in your data if I look correctly ("entities")

```
NSDictionary *entitiesDict = [[dict objectAtIndex: 1] objectForKey:@"entities"];
```

Use NSDictionary as mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDictionary instead of NSArray and set the values for elements in key. check this link for more idea.

> http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-fetch-and-parse-json/